# How can I fix Python video playing on Ubuntu using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, video, multiprocessing

On [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish), I am trying to play a video clip using the following code:

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

video_path = sys.argv[1]

def process_play_video(clip: VideoFileClip, video_fps: int):
    clip.preview(fps=video_fps)

clip = VideoFileClip(str(video_path))
video_fps = 15
play_directly = True

if play_directly:
    process_play_video(clip, video_fps)
else:
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_play_video,
                                       args=(clip, video_fps))
    process1.start()
    process1.join()

clip.close()
```

I have a video clip with the following video format:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output_video.mp4':
 Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 512
   compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
   encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
 Duration: 00:10:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2155 kb/s
 Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1954 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : VideoHandler
     vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
 Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : SoundHandler
     vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

which can be replayed without problems when I play that video directly (`play_directly = True`). However, when I start it in an own process (`play_directly = False`) the playing of the same video file does not work. I only see the first frame and nothing else happens.

I also have a different video file that can be played in both ways.

How can I figure out why this is happening and how can I fix it? It has to work with `moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip`, and it has to work with `multiprocessing` as shown in the code example.

Comment: I'm testing on Windows, not Ubuntu, so I won't post this as an answer. But I recommend creating and closing `clip` within the function `process_play_video()`. I'm not sure the exact details, but objects passed between processes need to be serialized, which might cause problems with your `VideoFileClip`. Better to create and close it entirely in the child process.

Comment: @BrendanMitchell  Thanks you for that suggestion, but this did not help solve my problem. The video still hangs

Comment: After more investigation the reason might be that video clips containing audio cannot be played with multiprocessing. Maybe the processes do miss some rights/output/access/whatever?